# If $\nabla\cdot u=0$, then $\nabla\cdot(u\otimes u)=(u\cdot\nabla)u$. Why does the lhs "make sense for more singular vector fields" than the rhs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics, divergence-operator

Suppose $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ is open and $u\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ with $\nabla\cdot u=0$. Then, $$\nabla\cdot(u\otimes u)=\underbrace{(\nabla\cdot u)u}_{=0}+(u\cdot\nabla)u=(u\cdot\nabla)u\;.\tag 1$$ Now, [I've read that the left-hand side "makes sense for more singular vector fields" than the right-hand side](http://tinyurl.com/jm255f3) of $(1)$.

> Why?

I don't see that. Both sides contain the first partial derivatives of $u$.

Comment: After having taken a look at the page that you link to, it seems to me that you heavily distort the claim in that book: those authors claim that the form of the NS system found at page 204 lends itself better to reformulation in terms of weak solutions that the form of the NS system found at page 203. Your question, though, asks about a completely different thing.

Comment: @AlexM. I guess you're write. I don't have access to page 203. Maybe if I had seen that they presented another version of the system on the page before, I had correctly understood them in the first place. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The system on page 203 has $u \cdot \nabla u$ instead of $\text{div} (u \otimes u)$, this is the only difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is not exactly because of the quadratic nature of $u \otimes u$, but rather because it is in "divergence form" when written as $\nabla \cdot( u \otimes u)$.  In this case we can understand this term in weak formulation by formally integrating by parts.  This is equivalent to formulating things in the sense of distributions.

Let's ignore the other terms for the moment and suppose I want to solve
$$
\nabla \cdot (u\otimes u)= f 
$$
for some given smooth $f$.  In this form it looks like I need to actually find a differentiable $u$ in order to make sense of the equations since 
$$
\nabla \cdot (u\otimes u) = (\nabla \cdot u) u + u \cdot \nabla u
$$
On the other hand, if we use the observation that if we multiply the equation by $\varphi \in C^\infty_c$ and integrate by parts, then 
$$
-\int u\otimes u : D \varphi = \int f \cdot \varphi.
$$
The weak formulation of the above problem is that this holds for all such $\varphi$.  The advantage of this approach is that it makes sense (i.e. the integrals are well-defined) under the very weak assumption that $u \in L^2$.  This allows us to bypass any differentiability assumptions and therefore allows "more singular vector fields."

Comment: Your answer gives an overview of what Sobolev derivatives are, but misses the point of the question. The OP asks whether the l.h.s. of that equality holds for a space *even larger* than $H_0^1$. I don't see how your very general considerations address this.

Comment: The requirements for $u$ are simply that it belongs to $L^2_{loc}$.  This is a significantly larger class of functions than $H^1_0$.  If you look in the book that OP links to this is precisely what is done after the quoted comment: the vector fields are only required to be locally in $L^2$.

Comment: Indeed, and it is not clear to me where the OP came up with $H_0^1$ which is not found in that book. As discussed in the comments above, it seems that the question is the OP's personal interpretation of the text, which does not faithfully reflect the content of the book, rendering our dicussion here meaningless.

Comment: There is an index $i$ on the left-hand side of your second equation, but not on the right-Hand side. Is $(u\otimes u)$ the $i$th column or the $i$th row of $u\otimes u$? And I'm not familiar with the Notation $u\otimes u\color{red}{:}{\rm D}\varphi$ (and shouldn't it be $\nabla\varphi$?).

Comment: The $i$ was a typo: I fixed it.  Here $D\varphi$ is the derivative matrix (sometimes called Jacobian matrix).  It's the same as $\nabla \varphi$, just a notational difference. Here $:$ is the dot product for matrices, i.e. $M: N = \sum_{i,j} M_{ij}N_{ij}$.  The formula stated just follows by integrating by parts / applying the divergence theorem.

Comment: With the divergence theorem in mind, I understand why the relation $(u\cdot\nabla u)=\nabla\cdot(u\otimes u)$ might be useful for the weak formulation of the Navier-Stokes equations. However, I've seen that this relation is used in the mild formulation too (see, for example, [here](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~gallay/NotesToulouse.pdf) on page 12, equation (2.14)). I don't see the benefit of $\nabla\cdot(u\otimes u)$ over $(u\cdot\nabla)u$ in that case. Do you know why this is done?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that $u \otimes u$ is quadratic in $u$, therefore smoother than just $u$. Maybe the following analogy will clarify things: while $\sqrt x$ is not smooth in $0$, the quadratic term $\sqrt x \cdot \sqrt x = x$ obviously is. A similar thing happens in your case: the larger the power, the smoother your term gets.

Comment: Still don't get it. Why is $u\otimes u$ quadratic in $u$? And in which sense exactly does $\nabla\cdot(u\otimes u)$ make sense for more singular vector fields? If I understand this correctly, they mean that $\nabla\cdot(u\otimes u)$ is applicable for $u$ in a larger class than $H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$. Which class exactly?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: That $u \otimes u$ is a quadratic expression is obvious, being positive-homogeneous of degree $2$. On the other hand, the above answer was meant to give you an intuitive understanding of what happens there, it was not meant to rigorously address your precise situation. Let me see whether I can come up with something closer to your needs. (The idea is that I feel that I understand what is meant there, even though I cannot put this in words.)